# Json array in php as a tree format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this php code to form the hierarchy

```
    $arr = array(
    'name' => "Level 2: A",
    'parent' => "Top Level",
    'children' => ""
);

$arr2 = array(
    'name' => "Top Level",
    'parent' => "null",
    'children' => "$arr"
);

echo json_encode($arr2);
```

But i cant access the array in the JSON output.

MY output from JSON:    {"name":"Top Level","parent":"null","children":"Array"}

My goal is to create an array like this but with JSON but it returns as an `array` instead of the data inside the `array`

```
var treeData = [
{
"name": "Top Level",
"parent": "null",
"children": [
  {
     "name": "Level 2: A",
     "parent": "Top Level",
     "children": [
      {
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 2: B",
    "parent": "Top Level"
  }
]
```

}
];

Comment: Why `'children' => "$arr"`?? Should be `'children' => array($arr)` or `'children' => $arr`. [Example](https://3v4l.org/ZSmu5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remvoe quotes abour `$arr`

```
$arr2 = array(
    'name' => "Top Level",
    'parent' => "null",
    'children' => $arr // <- remove quotes here
);
```

When you do `"$arr"`, you're actually converting `$arr` to string. That's why you have just `Array` string in JSON.

Moreover I would suggest to change `children` property in `$arr` to empty array instead of empty string:

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => "Level 2: A",
    'parent' => "Top Level",
    'children' => array() // <- here
);
```

This will make your code consistent, since you will always have an array under `children` property.